# Global Key or Localization Key values not getting correct values, once Updated with new value. in kentico 12. in same domain

Tags: kentico

Global Key or Localization Key values not getting correct values, once Updated with new value. in kentico 12. in same domain QC environment. in Devlopment its coming immediately. How to make the Updated Value must be get immediately by other web portal/site.as now its getting old_value.

Both CMS and WebSite in same domain. even not get immediate edited values/updated new vaues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use Kentico MVC, correct?

Sync between CMS and site works the same way as with web farm: 2 or more physical site instances use the same database. When you change any value through one of those instances is saves data into DB, but other instances might have that value cached, so web farm take care about letting know all the instances they need to drop the section of cache where value is being stored.

This being said you need to check if there are any web farm related issue. I'd start from checking web farm application in CMS and checking the event log for related errors. You might also enable debug for web farm in CMS setting and check it out.